# Ssh socks server doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, tunneling, socks

I want setup socks server on my localhost which forward all http traffic on my remote server for bypass firewall rules at my work net.
And so I start it as usually

```
sudo ssh -C2qTnN -D localhost:8080 -i myAWSKey.pem ubuntu@someserver.com
```

And set proxy settings in my browser. But then I try going to everywhere it's raise error "The connection was reset".
Why it's doesn't work maybe Amazone denied this feature?

**p.s** and yes I have option AllowTcpForwarding yes at my server's sshd_config

my host system ubuntu 12.10 and server is ubuntu 12.04

Comment: What proxy settings have you set in your browser, exactly?

Comment: Ssh -D option enables socks proxy (common port is 1080). 8080 may suggest that you mixed http and socks proxy types.

Comment: @MadHatter I use firefox and setuo localhost 8080 for all services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proxy built into ssh is a SOCKS proxy, not an HTTP or any other kind of proxy.  That said, it's capable of proxying http, as well as just about anything else TCP-based, for a SOCKS-capable client.  Firefox is such a client.

You need to make sure that in your browser proxy settings, the entries for HTTP, SSL and FTP proxy are **blank**; only SOCKS proxy should be host localhost and port 8080.

Comment: Yeah, its work, i looks like a full idiot right now ))

Comment: <GRIN> not to worry, you'd look an even bigger idiot if you hadn't asked!